# Interference beetween ADC samples with XBee and photoresistor

Tags: arduino, sensor, adc, xbee, sampling

I'm using an XBee serie 2 module for sampling the values of three sensors, a photoresistor (LDR) a moisture sensor and a temperature sensor (LM35). When there is no brightness the photoresistor has the maximum value (1023), but if the environment is very very dark the value is the same 1023, but the other sensors begin to be instable giving values ​​greater than normal. Maybe an XBee ADC sampling problem? or could be a circuit problem?

The XBee module I'm using for sampling, use a cyclic sleep mode: it wakes for 100ms and stay sleep for 3 minutes.. I tried to use a greater wake time like 1s but the problem is always there.

This is the scheme:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUsfxY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a picture:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9029111/IMG_4712.JPG

I think it's a power problem, because if I put a 1Kohm resistence near R2 the moisture sensor is ok, and the temperature varies very little to vary the brightness

Comment: Are all three sensors sharing a common ADC via a multiplexer? If so, try sampling the different inputs with a bigger time-gap between them

Comment: Please be more accurate than `giving values ​​greater than normal`

Comment: jippie, I mean that when there is brightness i have values like this: brightness=300, temperatur=440, umidity=150; and this is right; but when there is no brightness i have values like: brightness=1023, and temperatur=990 and umidity=1005. brightness is right because when it is dark the value is at maximum, but temperatur and umidity should stay with their original value

Comment: Andy aka, I don't know; im'using only an XBee module for sampling; i have only linked the sensors to the D0, D1 and D2 pin of the XBee module.

Comment: Please add a picture of your setup and a circuit diagram (hit Ctrl-M while editing your question).

Comment: Try substituting a 10K pot across the rails for each of the sensors in turn, and verify that you can send good values.  If they are noisy, try adding .1uF capacitors between the inputs and ground, since you don't need to measure high frequency signals.  Also you should probably use a current limit resistor with your LED, otherwise you may overtax the module output, which could perhaps even effect its analog performance.

Comment: What ADC reference voltage are you using for the Xbee?

Answer (score 2):

Check the datasheet for the ATmega that is on your Arduino for 'ADC Noise Reduction mode`.

> To enter any of the six sleep modes, the SE bit in SMCR must be written to logic one and a SLEEP instruction must
>   be executed. The SM2, SM1, and SM0 bits in the SMCR
>   Register select which sleep mode (Idle, ADC Noise
>   Reduction, Power-down, Power-save, Standby, or Extended Standby) will be activated by the SLEEP instruction.

Unfortunately, as far as I can see, you will have to write your own alternative for `analogRead();` as the standard library seems not to support that the sleep command.

Check [this article on arduino.cc](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/ArduinoSleepCode) for details on sleep.

Comment: Thankyou jippie, but for sampling i'm not using Arduino but only XBee module.. this module send the values to an Arduino with an XBee Shield; do you think the problem should be into the Arduino?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood then.